# Notification with actions

Tags: java, android, android-notifications

I am using this code for notification:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, NotificationManager.class);
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);

        Notification mNotification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)

            .setContentTitle("title")
            .setContentText("Text")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.office_girl)
            .setContentIntent(pIntent)
   //         .setSound(soundUri)
            .addAction(R.drawable.office_girl, "View", pIntent)
            .addAction(0, "Remind", pIntent)
            .build();

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0, mNotification);
```

The code works, beside the fact that th notification appears with no buttons - only title and text.

Further more when i click the notification my NotificationManager activity is not started...

My app minium SDK is 8, and targetsdk is 16.

For the NotificationCompat class i added android.support.v4.app jar.

I am testing my app on Android 4.1.2 OS (if it matters).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as the actions go, I'm pretty sure you don't see them because your notification is collapsed. Try grabbing the notification with two fingers and dragging down, that should exposed them. The notifications in Android 4.1+ are expandable.

As far as the `Activity` you're trying to launch goes, are you certain you've added it to your Manifest?